# Entity Framework 6.1.3; code first migrations many to many joined table

Tags: ef-code-first

I have generated a localDB, using code first migrations in my VS project. I have a many-to-many relationship between two entities (`Recipe` and `Ingredient`).

My Model classes:

```
public class Recipe
{
    [Key]
    public int RecipeId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Ingredient> Ingredients { get; set; }  
}

public class Ingredient
{
    [Key]
    public int IngredientId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool Organic { get; set; }
    public bool Vegan { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Recipe> Recipes { get; set; } 

}
```

The schema I generate with EF turns out the following:

[image: Table Overview]

A joined table named `RecipeIngredients` contains two foreign keys (`RecipeId` and `IngredientId`), which is what I'm after, but...

**Problem:** I want to have an extra column (`Quantity`) in the `RecipeIngredient` table. How do I solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It isn't possible to add any additional column to the connection table generated automatically by the Entity Framework.

You should create a new entity `RecipeIngredient` with all information you need and define one-to many relationship between `RecipeIngredient` and `Ingredient` and another one between `RecipeIngredient` and `Ingredient`.

```
public class Recipe {
    [Key]
    public int RecipeId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<RecipeIngredient> Ingredients { get; set; }  
}

public class Ingredient {
    [Key]
    public int IngredientId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool Organic { get; set; }
    public bool Vegan { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<RecipeIngredient> Recipes { get; set; } 
}

public class RecipeIngredient {
    [Key, Column(Order = 0)]
    public int RecipeID { get; set; }
    [Key, Column(Order = 1)]
    public int IngredientID { get; set; }
    public double Quantity { get; set; }
}
```